# Android chaining tasks and use results on each before executed task on chain

Tags: android

i'm trying to make this strategies on my android application:

make a chain for 3 task such as :for example

1. getProfile
2. getUserProducts
3. checkMoney

after get `getProfile` use retrieved data from that and using for `getUserProducts` and after get data with `getUserProducts` i want to check user money

this chain must be start from `1` and finished on `3`

how can i make this chain tasks?

Comment: Consider RxJava: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava

Comment: You'll have to implement a callback mechanism. Which basically means that you need to create a function that allows you to trigger a method after an operation is completed. How you do this totally depends on what kind of operations getProfile etc. are.

Comment: @KenWolf is any sample code to know how can i make this mechanism with RxJava?

Answer (score 0):

This is a fast example on how to use RxJava's DisposableSingleObserver. Create 3 methods and execute them one by one. OnSuccess of the first one, execute the second etc...

```
Single.create(sub -> {

                doSomethingHere

                sub.onSuccess(true);
            }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    //.compose(bindToLifecycle())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new DisposableSingleObserver<Object>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Object o) {

                          ExecuteTheNextThing();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {

                          errorHandling 

                        }
                    });
        }
```

You need to add these to your build gradle, to get the necessary libs.

```
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:+'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:+'
```